# Increment Days to a Start Date column using an Int column and fill a temporary table with all the dates

Tags: sql, date, increment

I have a table with this information: Customer (a varchar customer ID), DayInterval (Int), StartDate (date), EndDate (date). This is the code and results if i were to select from that table:

```
SELECT Customer, DayInterval, StartDate,EndDate
FROM CustomerTable
```

The results look like this:

```
Customer1,7,2020-01-01,2020-12-31
Customer2,14,2020-01-01,2020-12-31
Customer3,28,2020-01-01,2020-12-31
```

I need to create a table showing each customer and the dates that their DayInterval falls on. For example, Customer3 has a date for every 28 days so the table would show:

```
Customer3,2020-01-01
Customer3,2020-01-29
Customer3,2020-02-26
Customer3,2020-03-25
```

All the way up to their end date of 2020-12-31. Please can anyone help and sincere apologies if I haven't explained this very well!

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a recursive CTE.  The idea is:

```
with recursive cte as (
      select Customer, DayInterval, StartDate, EndDate
      from CustomerTable
      union all
      select customer, DayInterval, StartDate + DayInterval * interval '1 day', EndDate
      from cte
      where startdate < enddate
     )
select customer, startdate
from cte
order by customer, startdate;
```

Note that this uses generic SQL syntax.  The specific syntax might vary, depending on the database you are actually using.